# S3 Bucket Content Downloaded Instead of Displaying Page - Content-Type Set to HTML

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have encountered an issue while attempting to update the content of an S3 bucket. When I click on the bucket link, the browser immediately starts downloading the HTML source instead of rendering the page. I have verified that the Content-Type of the HTML file is correctly set to text/html. Despite this, the issue persists.

CloudFront Distribution

I am using CloudFront for content distribution.
CloudFront is configured to point to the S3 bucket as its origin.
I have invalidated the CloudFront cache after making updates.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Cleared the browser cache to rule out client-side caching issues.
Executed an invalidation on CloudFront to ensure the distribution of fresh content.
Verified the Content-Type of the HTML file in S3, and it is correctly set to text/html.
Checked for errors in the browser console, but there are no apparent issues.

Comment: What headers you're getting from CloudFront?